# How to write something in between two ".col-md-*"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write an "or" in between 2 ".col-md-1".
For example:

Green or Blue

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Green</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

What should I write inside the code or should I try another technique?

Comment: Can you explain what is the condition and how you decide to use each of them?

Comment: OP never used the word 'condition', and hasn't tagged the question javascript.

Comment: I'd probably simply go with an absolutely positioned pseudo element (on the basis that the word "or" is probably not the most important part here, and the UI would still make sense to users if it was missing - so it does not necessarily need to be part of the HTML, but could be inserted via CSS.)

Comment: @ovokuro stop being an OP yourself... let him ask the question

Answer (score 1):

You could add another `col-md-1` between the 2 elements (or whatever column size suits your needs):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Green</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <p>or</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how the result should look like. You can do something like this for example:

```
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <button class="btn"> Green </button> or <button class="btn"> Blue </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Give them and ID.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-1" id="green">
  <button class="btn">Green</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1" id="blue">
  <button class="btn">Blue</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

and then you can select the first one and append an element after it

```
$("$green").after('<div>OR</div>')
```

Answer (score -3):

give them an ID & do the if else in Javaascript

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="greenDiv" class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Green</button>
   </div>
   <div id= "redDiv" class="col-md-1">
      <button class="btn">Blue</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

in js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     if(someCondition == true){
        $("#redDiv").show();
        $("#greenDiv").hide();
     }else{
        $("#redDiv").hide();
        $("#greenDiv").show();
     }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don' t know how to do the "if else" in Javaascript my friend.

Comment: Could you tell more about the condition & when you are going for "or" ???

Comment: @ovokuro I have elaborated

Comment: The OP says in the question `I am trying to **write*** an "or" in between`, so that that it will look like `Green or Blue` and not to display one or the other.